# Why my error is not getting catch by except?

Tags: python, error-handling, bluetooth-lowenergy, mqtt

I've been trying to solve this all day, did a bunch of research, tried a lot of different approaches but none of them work. I currently have a code to connect to a bluetooth BLE device using bluepy, and when it connects works perfectly, but some times it doesn't connect and doesn't give error, just get sucked at the line [00:00:00:00:00] Connecting, and doesn't show in the "except". When I sent a new command, sometimes works, but since I don't get error, nor anything I'm never sure when I need to send a new command or not.

Below is the code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from bluepy import *
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import struct

### Variables

mqtt_client = ""
mqtt_port = 
mqtt_user = ""
mqtt_password = ""
mqtt_path = ""

####  Don't edit below here

open = "\x00\xff\x00\x00\x9a\x0d\x01\x00\x96"
close = "\x00\xff\x00\x00\x9a\x0d\x01\x64\xf2"

def shade_command(fble, fcmd):
      try:
        print "["+ fble + "] Connecting"
        dev = btle.Peripheral(fble)
        print "["+ fble + "] Connected!"
        chs = dev.getCharacteristics()
        for ch in chs:
          if ch.uuid == "0000fe51-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb":
            ch.write(fcmd)
        dev.disconnect
        print  "["+ fble + "] Disconnected"
      except:
        print "["+ fble + "] Error Connecting"

# The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected to MQTT with result code "+str(rc))

    # Subscribing in on_connect() means that if we lose the connection and
    # reconnect then subscriptions will be renewed.
    client.subscribe(mqtt_path + "/#")

# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    if msg.payload == "open":
        address = msg.topic.replace(mqtt_path + "/", "")
        result = shade_command(address, open)
        if result == True:
          print msg.topic + "/status"
          client.publish(msg.topic + "/status", "on", qos=0, retain=False)
    if msg.payload == "close":
        address = msg.topic.replace(mqtt_path + "/", "")
        result = shade_command(address, close)
        if result == True:
          client.publish(msg.topic + "/status", "off", qos=0, retain=False)
          print msg.topic + "/status"

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.username_pw_set(mqtt_user, password=mqtt_password)
client.connect(mqtt_client, mqtt_port, 60)
```

The issue is happening here:

```py
def shade_command(fble, fcmd):
      try:
        print "["+ fble + "] Connecting"
        dev = btle.Peripheral(fble)
        print "["+ fble + "] Connected!"
        chs = dev.getCharacteristics()
        for ch in chs:
          if ch.uuid == "0000fe51-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb":
            ch.write(fcmd)
        dev.disconnect
        print  "["+ fble + "] Disconnected"
      except:
        print "["+ fble + "] Error Connecting"
```

When I try to connect to a MAC address and doesn't work I don't get an error, just stop after this part of the code:

```py
        print "["+ fble + "] Connecting"
        dev = btle.Peripheral(fble)
```

The last thing I see is a [00:00:00:00:00] Connecting and nothing else! I was expecting to see the except code.

Below is one output example, it first try to connect when I send an MQTT command, but nothing happens, it just stop, than I sent another command and it works, I know it works when it shows "Connecting", "Connected!" and "Disconnected"

```sh
[02:B3:CD:3D:C5:34] Connecting
[02:B3:CD:3D:C5:34] Connecting
[02:B3:CD:3D:C5:34] Connected!
[02:B3:CD:3D:C5:34] Disconnected
```

**Edit 1:**

Tried to use the except code below but didn't work:

```py
except btle.BTLEException as e:
```

**Edit 2:**

Thanks to @hardillb now I know the paho mqtt is the one catching the error and ignoring them, I added this piece of code and now I can see when the error occurs:

```py
def on_log(client, userdata, level, buff):  # mqtt logs function
    print buff

client.on_log = on_log
```

It shows like this when I have an error:

```
Caught exception in on_message: global name 'traceback' is not defined
```

Comment: You should allow the error to show up in order to be able to debug it. Please, remove the ```except``` and run it till it breaks. Then see what is the error and work from there. This is one of the reasons why we should avoid using bare ```except``` and specify the exception class as well. Errors are a good thing and must be there in order to help you debug your code and avoid silent fails.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  Your code has several anomalies,  including an undefined symbol and a loop you don't use.

Comment: Most of all, what do you believe will throw a run-time exception for you to catch?  Did that exception actually arise?  Where is your debugging trace -- insert a `print` statement or two to track your progress and values.

Comment: What's the point in the `break` after your `return True`? This can't be reached.

Comment: According to this documentation you are not catching the exceptions correctly. 

https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/97794/bluepy.btle.BTLEException

Comment: Even without try I get the same issue, the function just stops and execute the next one. I did use btle.BTLEException and BTLEException, gave me the same result. Since it's not that large, I'm adding the full code.

Comment: `on_message` is called on the MQTT client's network thread and is wrapped in a try/expect block that will catch and ignore all errors. If you remove the try/expect block in `shade_command` you not get a crash

Answer (score 0):

Thanks hardillb Looks like having the try/except outside the function did the trick!

The new code is like this:

Function:

```py
def shade_command(fble, fcmd):
    print "["+ fble + "] Connecting"
    dev = btle.Peripheral(fble)
    print "["+ fble + "] Connected!"
    chs = dev.getCharacteristics()
    for ch in chs:
      if ch.uuid == "0000fe51-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb":
        ch.write(fcmd)
    dev.disconnect
    print  "["+ fble + "] Disconnected"
```

Calling the function:

```py
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    if msg.payload == "open":
        try:
          address = msg.topic.replace(mqtt_path + "/", "")
          result = shade_command(address, open)
          print msg.topic + "/status"
          client.publish(msg.topic + "/status", "on", qos=0, retain=False)
        except:
          print "Error"
```